# Excel index missing from sheet but included within formula

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a gantt chart that has some conditional formatting in it. The problem im having is that I cannot see where the "ganttTypes" array is stored in my excel sheet.

```
=IF($N$2=INDEX(ganttTypes,1),IF(AND(H$5>=$C6,H$5<=$C6+$D6),IF($C6+$D6*$G6>H$5,$Y$2,""),""),IF(AND(H$5>=$E6,H$5<=$E6+$F6),IF($E6+$F6*$G6>H$5,$Y$2,""),""))
```

From looking at different sources online there is an indication that "gantTypes" is a particular cell and the "1" next to it indicates the row next to that cell -  - [here is an example where it explains that](http://skp.mvps.org/xl00002.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I assume ganttTypes refers to a named range, in which case you should be able to locate it by using the Names Manager, which lists all the named ranges and their location, in Formulas / Defined Names.